# ros2 concatenate LaunchConfiguration with string for function argument

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a ros2 python launch script, I want to concatenate a LaunchConfiguration with a string and pass it to a function. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
def load_file(package_name, file)
   # body of function

prefix = LaunchConfiguration("name")

# package_name = prefix + "_pkg"
contents = load_file(package_name, file)
```

Here package_name needs to be the concatenation of a LaunchConfiguration and a literal string. There must be a way I can do this - no?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393861/ros2-concatenate-launchconfiguration-with-string-for-function-argument/) by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2022-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, the only easy way* to concatenate a LaunchConfiguration with a string is by passing them as a list in any parameter of type "SomeSubstitutionsType" as shown [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/358655/ros2-concatenate-string-to-launchargument/).

*The harder convoluted way would be by using the OpaqueFunction as described in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/322636/ros2-access-current-launchconfiguration/?answer=359167#post-id-359167). It's feels hackier but gives more flexibility

---

Originally posted by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) with karma: 166 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thejeeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/54884/thejeeb/) on 2022-01-12**:
Since the parameter that needs the concatenation isn't a substitution type, the list method doesn't work. However, the OpaqueFunction approach works and I was able to get it to work. Thanks.